# Codeigniter 4 curlrequest() always returns {"CSP":{}}

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-4

Using Codeigniter 4.4.1

When making a curl request call $response is always **{"CSP":{}}**, no matter what endpoint I call.  CSP is NOT enabled: public bool *$CSPEnabled = false;*

I'm trying to do a token exchange with https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token

Here's the code:

```
//some fields left out for brevity
$lwa_auth = [ 'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
              'code' => $spapi_oauth_code' ];  
$curl = \Config\Services::curlrequest();
$response = $curl->request( 'POST', 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token', [
    'form_params' => $lwa_auth
] );
```

I created a test endpoint to test the POST:

```
class AuthTest extends ResourceController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'grant_type' => $this->request->getVar('grant_type'),
            'code' => $this->request->getVar('code'),
            'redirect_uri' => $this->request->getVar('redirect_uri'),
            'client_id' => $this->request->getVar('client_id'),
            'client_secret' => $this->request->getVar('client_secret')
        ];
        log_message('debug', 'Auth Test Data: ' . json_encode( $data ) );
        return $this->response->setJSON( [ 'status' => 'success' ] );
    }
}
```

When I modify the curl request to post to the test endpoint, I end up with the expected data in the log file, but the response is **{"CSP":{}}**

When I call the test endpoint from Postman, I get the correct response: *{ "status": "success" }*

When I call the https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token endpoint from Postman I also get the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've been working on this app all day, and I'm generally used to standard PHP cURL.  It finally dawned on me that $response is an *object*, not a *string*.  I blame lack of coffee.

However, I am puzzled as to why json_encoding the object resulted in {"CSP":{}}, and did not serialize all the properties of the object.